Asyncio.ensure_future not working as intended when trying to call async function from a kivy file
I am trying to call a async function through a kivy file, however the code complains that there is no await inside the kivy code, so now I am using the Clock function to make that happen.
Here is my code for the kivy file:
Button:
id: heart
width: 100
center_x: root.width * 0.5
center_y: root.height * 0.5
size_hint: None, None
size: 524, 225
background_normal: "Images/heart_pixelated.png"
on_press: root.schedule_baseline()

Here is my code for the python file:
def schedule_baseline(self):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.run_async_baseline)

def run_async_baseline(self, dt):
    print('running async baseline')

    asyncio.ensure_future(self.find_baseline_wrapper())

async def find_baseline_wrapper(self):
    print('inside the find baseline wrapper')
    await self.queue.put(None)
    await self.find_baseline()
    await self.queue.get()

I got this code from doing multiple research and some chatgpt code, however when I run this, the print('running async baseline') will work but the print('inside the find baseline wrapper') does not seem to run, so I have concluded that the error is caused by the asyncio.ensure_future line of code.
any help appreciated!

Calling asyncio.ensure_future(self.find_baseline_wrapper()) creates a coroutine, but doesn't wait for it to execute (you never await on the returned value). It looks like maybe you want asyncio.run(self.find_baseline_wrapper()), but without seeing the rest of your code it's not clear why find_baseline_wrapper is async in the first place.
